# WolframScript fails to activate

Tags: licensing, free-wolfram-engine

When I try to run wolframscript for the first time, here is what happens

```
$ wolframscript 

The Wolfram Engine requires one-time activation on this computer.

Visit https://wolfram.com/engine/free-license to get your free license.

Wolfram ID: my-email@gmail.com
Password: 
The Wolfram Engine exited during an activation attempt because of a license error: invalid activation key entered.
```

I already went to `https://wolfram.com/engine/free-license` and activated my license

[image]

I tried with two different accounts on two different computers, and it failed with both.

Comment: You need to install engine version as root user and restart the terminal line to input your user register name and password.

Comment: That's what I did, already

Comment: Ditto. `The Wolfram Engine exited during an activation attempt because an error occurred.` There does not appear to be a log. I checked in `/opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Download the free [engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) and install it. On Unix:

```
$ sudo ./Wolfram*sh
```

[Get your free license](https://account.wolfram.com/access/wolfram-engine/free), sign in and accept the terms of use. In the command line:

```
$ wolframscript

The Wolfram Engine requires one-time activation on this computer.

Visit https://wolfram.com/engine/free-license to get your free license.

Wolfram ID: xxxxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
Password: 
Wolfram Engine activated. See https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/ for more information.
Wolfram Language 13.0.1 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2022 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Exit[]
```

The second time around the same command will not ask for uname+pwd.